# Select dropdown to input text with predefined values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form the Powerrange field is used to create a URL, but the value needed is different to the input one! so we need to predefine them.

```
<form id="form">

 <input type="text" id="powerrange"><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="location" value="store" checked/><label>America</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="store.au"/><label>Australia and Oceania</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="store.au"/><label>Africa</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="store.au"/><label>Asia</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="store"/><label>Europe</label><br><br>
```

Ok this is what I have so far:

```
function goToPage(){
var location = $('input[name=location]:checked').val();
var idConversions = {"100":14,"101":5000}
$('#powerrange').keyup(function(){
    var correctId = idConversions[$(this).val()];
        });

window.location.href = "http://"+location+".domain.com/catalog.aspx?section="+correctId+"";
```

}

Comment: Side note, is there any way to convert the system so that the value and final number are the same? Any way to make 100 = 100 and translate better, so you can avoid converting?

Comment: Yes I know! but it's not possible! Those values are predefined but another module! so I need to use them!

Comment: It's ok, I figured. Having to deal with constraints because of other developers is a daily thing.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER:** replaces `select>` with `<input>`, validates input entry against textual values of current options.

```
var minLengthRanges = 10000;
var ranges = $('#powerrange option').map(function () {
    var data = {
        val: this.value,
        section: $(this).text()
    }
    if (data.section.length < minLengthRanges) {
        minLengthRanges = data.section.length;
    }
    return data

}).get();


var currVal = $('#powerrange option:selected').text();
$('#powerrange').replaceWith('<input id="powerrange" type="number" value="' + currVal + '"/>');

$('#powerrange').keyup(function () {
    var val = this.value
    if (!val || val.length < minLengthRanges) {
        return;
    }
    var isValid = checkIsValidRange(val);
    $('body').append('<p>Value is ' + (isValid ? '' : 'not') + ' a match</p>');
    if (isValid) {
        var url = '.........catalog.aspx?section=' + val;
        $('body').append('<p>URL is ' + url + '</p>');
    }
});


function checkIsValidRange(val) {
    var isValidRange = false;
    if (val && !isNaN(parseInt(val, 10))) {
        isValidRange = $.grep(ranges, function (item, index) {
            return item.section == val;
        }).length;
    }
    return isValidRange;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GnwcB/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a pre-defined array so that your code knows `100` = `14`. On `keyup`, `blur`, or `submit` or some form event that works for you, take the value of the text field, lookup the right value in the array, and then build your final link.

Here's a [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hvL7n/) of how it might be done

```
$(function(){

    var idConversions = {"100":14,"101":5000}

    $('#the-text-field').keyup(function(){
        var correctId = idConversions[$(this).val()];
        if( typeof correctId !== "undefined") alert(correctId); 
    });

});
```

If you need to maintain a similar array on server-side code, try to find a way to share the list so you're not defining the "conversion matrix" in two places. Like build the array server-side in php or something, print it as JSON.

Comment: Clever! Man If you could give me a hand with a sample code! I'll appreciate it!

Comment: It's getting there! You have the idea! but I can't get it working! We need to convert the inputed value! and add the correct value in the URL! Check my post please! I just updated it !

Comment: You need to have the new link generated inside the function, and you also need to retain the undefined check I had